# jboss and using multiple log4j.properties

Tags: jboss7.x

I am using jbossAS 7.1 multiple war files are deployed in it. I want to use different log4j.properties for each war. I have added -Dlog4j.configuration= path/log.properties file. Do I need to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [remove](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers log4j dependency on your deployment then just make sure your `log4j.properties` is on your class path. Usually you just need to make sure it's in your `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` directory.